# Create delegate at runtime from native method on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

This is a **MonoTouch-specific** question.

I'm currently developing a wrapper for OpenGL which is quite different from wrappers like OpenTK. This wrapper is used to enable faster development with OpenGL.

Methods are not declared like this: `void glGenTextures(Int32 n, UInt32[] textures);`, they are declared like `void glGenTextures(Int32 count, [Out]TextureHandle[] textures)` where `TextureHandle` is a structure with the same size as a `UInt32`.

### Question

On Windows i can use `GetProcAddress`, `wglGetProcAddress` and `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to create a delegate from a method pointer, but how to do this on iOS with MonoTouch. Is there any way to this or is it not supported by monotouch yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Starting with MonoTouch 5.4](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.4#Support_for_creating_Managed_Delegates_from_C_Function_Pointers) this is possible. You need to create a delegate with the same signature as the managed method, and decorate it with the `MonoNativeFunctionWrapper` attribute:

```
[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]
public delegate void glGenTexturesDelegate (int n, uint[] textures);
```

Now you can call the method:

```
var del = (glGenTexturesDelegate) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer (pointer);
del (n, textures);
```

That said, I believe you're doing this a lot more complicated than you need to. Just use a P/Invoke:

```
[llImport("libGLESv2.dll")]
extern static void glGenTextures (int n, uint[] textures);
```

and then call it like this:

```
glGenTextures (n, textures);
```

Comment: I need to test it later this day, but there is still the question: How to get the function pointer of the method. OF course the extern static void would work, but i have a load process which allows me to use the same wrapper for different plattforms without using defines. If getting the pointer isn't working i still can wrap the delegates to the imported method.

Comment: Actually after over 2 years i want to use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` however, as long i don't know the pointer itself its useless.