# How to Invoke the IntPtr result of method_getImplementation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

The result of calling `method_getImplementation(method)` is an `IntPtr`.  How do I convert an `IntPtr` to a method?

```
[DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib")]
extern static IntPtr method_getImplementation(IntPtr method);

public void SomeMethod
{
var method = class_getInstanceMethod(new UIViewController().ClassHandle, new Selector("viewWillAppear:").Handle);

IntPtr original_impl = method_getImplementation(method);
}
```

In obj-c:

```
IMP originalImp = method_setImplementation(method,swizzleImp);
originalImp(self,_cmd)
```

Comment: Gotta be honest, this looks like the sort of plumbing the interop layer should be handling, since in general you just flat-out can't call arbitrary memory locations from managed code. So maybe a bit of an XY problem? What are you trying to do that involves this?

Comment: This, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127453/how-to-port-method-getimplementation-and-method-setimplementation-to-monotou

Comment: Hmm, maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767903/create-delegate-at-runtime-from-native-method-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` and add `[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]` to the delegate type:

```
[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]
public delegate void ViewWillAppearDelegate (IntPtr self, IntPtr selector);

var del = (ViewWillAppearDelegate) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer (original_impl, typeof (ViewWillAppearDelegate));
del (obj.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("viewWillAppear"));
```